# Why burn methane to CO2 for isotopic analyis?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, isotope

I am wondering why mathane is burned to CO$_2$ for isotopic analysis, e.g with a mass spec?
I have looked into several text books, they all describe how to do it but not why.
Is it because of a interference on mass 16? Analysing methane it it is would give you also information about the D/H ratio. So why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different types of mass spectrometers with different modes of sample introduction, analyte ionization and ion selection/focusing. You cannot generalize "with *a* mass spec."

In many cases of isotope ratio mass spectrometry (IRMS), compound specific isotopic analysis (CSIA), or Gas Chromatography Combustion Isotope Ratio Mass Spectrometry *organic compounds* (not just methane) are burned and oxidized to carbon dioxide and water and analyzed as such to determine the total ratio of carbon-13/carbon-12 and hydrogen-2/hydrogen-1. However, combustion is not the only way to introduce compounds in the mass spectrometer.

Another secondary issue is that there if often more noise at low mass ranges. Methane is a small molecule (m/z =16) and carbon dioxide is relatively large (m/z=44).

Comment: Sorry for being not that precise. Let's consider ambient air. So methane is extracted and afterwards burned to CO2 because of noise. With noise you mean mass interferences like H2O?

Comment: Noise, means noise overall (from the instrument) not interferences.

Comment: You are using improper notations for isotopes. For example, "C-13" should be either carbon-13 or $\ce{^{13}C}.$

Comment: I have edited it. I know you like to have perfection in symbolism but one cannot be too orthodox or rigid in notations. Too much rigidity makes it easy to break. Do a Google Book search of "C-13" NMR and you will find book titles with C-13 NMR, and of course plenty of publications.

Comment: Well, they are either wrong, or use something like "… C 13" for radiopharmaceuticals. Look, it's not me who came up with the [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope#Notation), but they make sense to me and allow for a hassle-free communication. Besides, the ACS Style Guide, which is taken exemplary in this community as well as by US publishers of chemical literature, [also prescribes these notations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGfap.png). Also, we are still not quite there, the names of chemical elements should not be capitalized unless they are the first words of a sentence.

Comment: @andselisk - I think you are too rigid about formatting on this site. This site isn't an ACS publication. I certainly understood what C-13 meant. It sure is a lot easier to input than $\ce{^{13}C}$.

Comment: @maxw It doesn't matter whether it is easy or hard if it is *wrong*. However, please feel free to inform whether there is an applicable standard for writing "C-13". In the absence of one such notation should be treated similarly to a typo or a grammatical error, like "*kemztri*" in place of "chemistry". See, it is less symbols to type and is likely to be understood correctly in a context, but it is plain illiterate as it is simply not English language. Remember the analogy with the Tower of Babylon I use every time you raise the issue with the formatting guidelines being too complex.

Comment: @maxw It's part of my job as a mod to assure literate communication. See, the ACS Style Guide is not a hegemon. I cited ACS since M. Farooq is a resident of the US and these recommendations would be relevant for sure. Other authoritative sources such as IUPAC *Red Book* say the same, and this nomenclature is also used by ISO and in national standards such as DIN (Germany) or GOST (Russia).

Comment: @maxw Those who know the standardized notations around the world won't have to raise their eyebrows and wonder what was happening in OP's head at the moment of posting. That's the true way of making life easier, not accepting everything and being agreeable.

Comment: @andselisk, I respect ACS style guide and all other efforts by others to homogenize notations. My point in the comments was that the usage of "C-13" is not *that uncommon* in the literature even in respected Physics journals published by Americans. There are NMR books whose titles have "C dash thirteen" written on them  (American authors, of course they are field experts and the publisher is Springer). See for example springer.com/gp/book/9789400931619